# AWS S3, How to get the number of request per object in a month?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way for me to know how many times an object in my bucket has been requested ?

Comment: You can use aws cloud trail. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-request-identification.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which objects you care about in advance you can probably go the way [samtoddler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65541334/6485881) suggested. For a more generic approach there are two options:

1. You can [enable object-level](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html) logging in CloudTrail. CloudTrail will then track all API-calls concerning the bucket and you can parse the information from CloudTrail to get the desired info.
2. You can [enable server access logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html) in S3 and store access logs for the bucket into another bucket. You can then [use something like Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/analyze-logs-athena/) to compile more detailed statistics about any particular objects in your bucket.

Personally I'd go with option 2) as the format is a little easier to work with for simpler queries. For a comparison of the options take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/logging-with-S3.html). Note that these options are **not** mutually exclusive, you can use both if you like.

Answer (score 0):

can be done via [s3 metrics with Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html). Further, as per your use case, you can configure the filter by [object tag or prefix](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/configure-metrics-filter.html)